# How to get Scikit-learn model output from OrangeML model?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, orange

I wish to apply a python library on an Orange model (for example Orange Tree Classifier), however this library only accepts scikit-learn models. Is there a way to convert my Orange Tree Classifier in a Scikit-Learn tree Classifier including a Python script in my Orange pipes? I know Orange ML models are built on scikit learn library so they should theoretically be convertible.

Thanks in advance !
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of Orange models are built on Scikit-Learns's classifier but `TreeLearner` is not. However, there is the `SklTreeLearner` in Orange which wraps the `DecisionTreeClassifier` from Scikit. If you want to get the Scikit model out of the orange model use this one. Here is an example:

```
from Orange.classification import SklTreeLearner
from Orange.data import Table

learner = SklTreeLearner()
model = learner(Table("iris"))  # train model on Iris data
skl_model = model.skl_model  # get skl model
```

The same principle can be also used for other models that wrap Scikit models - LogisticRegression, RandomForest, ...

In order that you train your model in visual Orange, there is an option to get a skl_model with Python script widget. You connect the learner to the Python Script widget as it is shown at the screenshot below. It is important to connect the `Model` learners output to `Classifier` input on Python Script widget. Then get the Skl model with the following code in the Python Script widget.

```
skl_model = in_classifier.skl_model
```

Note: You can get the skl_learner from any learner except the Tree learner.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I cannot find how to build and train this SklTreeLearner through clicking and dropping in Orange 3, that I would then convert to scikit model by including a python script within the same Orange3 pipe with graphical interface. I dont understand what would be the added value of Orange if it was to be used as a casual Python module within python files. Thank you in advance, Martin

Comment: @becuwemartin I added an additional explanation on how to do that in the visual Orange. Note: In order that you just want to train on one dataset and test on another you can use Prediction widget in Orange: https://orange.biolab.si/widget-catalog/evaluation/predictions/